# How To Automatically Copy cell's value When a Cell with formula has a change in value?

Tags: events, google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Data for spreadsheet:** Economic Data Feed (name) - This spreadsheet contains 2 sheets, namely "Results" and "Triggers"

**What :** In my spreadsheet "Economic Data Feed" and sheet "Results" cell C5 contains a formula. This formula tells me whether or not a Bullish or a Bearish reversal has been elected based on data from the sheet "Stock Market Confidence".

It has 3 possible outcomes based on a IFS formula which is *"Bearish reversal elected" , "Bullish reversal elected" or "No reversal elected".*

**The challenge:** Whenever these reversals are elected, they are valid for let's say 6 months up until 1 year. They (the reversal elections) are based on economic data that is imported in the same spreadsheet. Since the economic data feed is being frequently updated a signal will therefore disappear. Which is the problem.

Imagine a reversal being elected one day, let's say a Bullish reversal, then the next day the economic data in the sheet "Stock Market Confidence" is updated and the signal disappears and the cell in C5 changes back to "No reversal elected".

**What I need:** Whenever the *cell C5 in the sheet "Results"* elects a reversal, I need the cell value (cell value only) automatically copied to another place in the same spreadsheet in another sheet that I envision calling "Reversal Elections". This is needed so that the signal does not disappear because, as mentioned, the economic data feed is being frequently updated. Furthermore I need the date of reversal election copied.

The following to screenshots are different sheets in the same spreadsheet:

[image: scr shot of sheet: Triggers]
[image: scr shot of sheet: Results]

**Ideal way this happens:**

1. Cell C5 in sheet "Results" elects a reversal based on the IFS formula
2. The value (and value only, not the formula) in C5 along with the
   date for the election reversal is being automatically copied to
   somewhere else, *preferably in the same spreadsheet in Triggers*.

Comment: No. `````````````````​`````````````````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can get a trigger to update values. The below code should work and I made [a sample file that might help](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GyM9s_8u2G5BSCgWmkfd6EIE7zuC1s-BLU9LMUGcwiU/edit?usp=sharing). If you duplicate it you can have your own version at see it.

You might want to [review here on event triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers).

The below code would probably work well for what I think you're looking for (keep in mind this is Stack Overflow so we don't know much about bulls and bears -- even the sports teams). This would write a new line on the log sheet any time the value in C5 changed. Note that this is using a formula comparison based on linked values in a formula in the LoggedResults Sheet in cell B1. If you play around with your own version of it, I think it might make more sense.

```
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */

/**
 * The event handler triggered when editing the spreadsheet.
 * @param {Event} e The onEdit event.
 */
function onEdit(e) {
  const cellsToCopyFromTop = "A1:C1"; ///<--- update these if you want to include more columns
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const logSheet= ss.getSheetByName('LogResults');

  //test to see if cell B1 matches value of last entry 
    if(logSheet.getRange("B1").getValue() !=
       logSheet.getRange(logSheet.getLastRow(),2).getValue()){
      var newValues = logSheet.getRange(cellsToCopyFromTop).getValues();
      logSheet.getRange(logSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,newValues.length,newValues[0].length).setValues(newValues);  
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there, and thank you so much for your reply and efforts! I truly appreciate it! I duplicated your spreadsheet and played around with it, I could not get it to work, but that must be my fault, probably. In the sheet "Results" I typed in various texts in Type and in Boink and I expected those texts to be copied to "LogResults" but it did not happen. What  am I missing?

Comment: Oh... never mind! I got it to work now! I just misunderstood how it worked.... I figured when I change the B5 cell to blank it copies it!

Comment: I added an answer to my post with some questions for you.

Comment: HI @mancoder. StackoverFlow has some pretty strict standards where you shouldn't post questions as answers. Additionally it's considered slightly bad form to ask additional unrelated questions after an answer provided. I realize this is all new to you, so no worries, but it would be most appreciated if you could accept my answer (by clicking check box).   A couple quick answers to what you wrote: that the +1 is needed to direct which row to add the new entry. The getLastRow() get's the last USED row, which would mean we would overwrite that entry. The 2 is the column. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry about that. I accepted your question now :-) Thanks a lot for helping and answering my follow up question too!